# Unfolding lists created by lambda function after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm applying a lambda function after grouping a dataframe by the index. This function adds two elements to the original groups.

```
df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: fun(x.col))
```

Where the function is:

```
def fun(x):
    return np.r_[np.repeat(x[:1],2),x,np.repeat(x[:-1],2)]
```

However it returns a list for each group,

```
33    [0.9526133823707408, 0.9526133823707408, 0.952...
14    [0.7399641356312007, 0.7399641356312007, 0.739...
16    [0.9932682467249898, 0.9932682467249898, 0.993...
40    [0.8378176113760183, 0.8378176113760183, 0.837...
```

How could I unfold these lists, so that I have each element in the list appear as a new row, with its corresponding index? (just as the original structure of the df)

I tryied adding a .apply(pd.Series) but that instead unfolds each element into a new column).

Original structure:

```
33    0.952613
33    0.929144
33    0.903109
33    0.876384
33    0.850252
33    1.185296
33    1.155291
33    1.119522
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series` for row for each `numpy array`:

```
def fun(x):
    return pd.Series(np.r_[np.repeat(x[:1],2),x,np.repeat(x[:-1],2)])

df = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: fun(x.col))   
print (df)
          0         1         2     ...           21        22        23
33  0.952613  0.952613  0.952613    ...     1.185296  1.155291  1.155291

[1 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: I'm getting `Wrong number of items passed 75, placement implies 25`.

Comment: Can you add some data sample and sample function?

Comment: Yes, just added them.